# CommunityEngine on rails3 not loading the theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, themes, communityengine

I installed a fresh version of CE from rails3 branch.
Every thing worked fine but the Theme.

I did downloaded the "dappled" theme put it in "ROOT/themes" folder.
Then added this line "theme: dappled" to the "application.yml" file.

Deleted the default "application.html.rb" file from "views/layouts" folder and "index.html" file from the "public" folder.

But still no theme at all loading !!

By the way i get this error in terminal log:

```
Started GET "/javascripts/community_engine.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-25 17:46:37 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/community_engine.js"):

Rendered /Users/walidov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.9ms)

Started GET "/stylesheets/community_engine.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-25 17:46:37 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/community_engine.css"):

Rendered /Users/walidov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.9ms)

Started GET "/images/spinner.gif" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-25 17:46:37 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/spinner.gif"):

Rendered /Users/walidov/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.beta1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)
```

I added this line "mount CommunityEngine::Engine => "/"" to the "routes.rb" file

Any help?